# Highcharts parse json string for x-axis grouped categories

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I'm working on a project in asp c# and using Highcharts for reporting.

I want to group the categories I have as a json string and I don't know how to push the data to x-axis categories.

> [{
>       "name": "CTS",
>       "categories": ["01AT", "02AT", "03AT", "04AT", "06AT"]
>   }, {
>       "name": "340_HSC",
>       "categories": ["02QHSC", "05QHSC", "07QHSC", "14QHSC"]
>   }]

Comment: are you using http://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/

Comment: yes im using blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories

Comment: check https://jsfiddle.net/4xjk8cLq/

Comment: wow thanks Deep 3015 this help me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your json string contains proper data format to pass as `xAxis` categories. 
So pass your json string as

```
$(function () {

var jsond=[{ "name": "CTS", "categories": ["01AT", "02AT", "03AT", "04AT", "06AT"] }, { "name": "340_HSC", "categories": ["02QHSC", "05QHSC", "07QHSC", "14QHSC"] }];

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: "container",
            type: "column"
        },
        title: {
            useHTML: true,
            x: -10,
            y: 8,
            text: '<span class="chart-title"> Grouped categories <span class="chart-href"> <a href="http://www.blacklabel.pl/highcharts" target="_blank"> Black Label </a> </span> <span class="chart-subtitle">plugin by </span></span>'
        },
        series: [{
            data: [4, 14, 18, 5, 6, 5, 14, 15, 18]
        }],
        xAxis: {
            categories: jsond
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4xjk8cLq/) demo